# I cant store checkbox value into session

Tags: php, session, checkbox, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am trying to put a checkbox value into a session. When I am trying to save it in Laravel, it saves the name field of the checkbox like `foo[].`

```
<ul class="check-square">
    <?php Session::put('selectsubservice', 'selectsubservice[]'); ?> @foreach($subservices as $subservice)
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="selectsubservice[]" value="{{$subservice->id}}">{{$subservice->name}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: no one is  available to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Session::put('selectsubservice', $subservice->id);`

You are passing the name of the input field as the argument to Session::put, that will not be automatically substituted. You need to pass the actual value to Session::put.